# Logging user's advanced informations

Tags: logging, server, freeradius

I am working with a free-radius server (2.2.5) and I am searching a way to save user's informations (@Mac, username, pc-name, brand? ...) when they logged.

Do you have any idea ? I have only found that it's possible to save username/password.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Radius can provide information

1. client ip address
2. client mac address
3. client wan ip address
4. date-time on logout
5. date time on accouting
6. bandwidth download/upload.

You can get these information save to database, if you use freeradius + mysql.